# Django ORM - How to left join on two conditions with many to many field

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two models:

```py
class Subscription(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Subscription)
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I need to simulate sql query through django orm

```sql
select * from newsletter_subscription ss
left join newsletter_mail_subscriptions ms
    on ss.id = ms.subscription_id and ms.mail_id = <mail_id>;
```

so I can see if the mail is subscribed to each subscription by getting the entire list of available subscriptions

i need something like FilteredRelated:

```py
q = Subscription.objects.annotate(
    is_subscribe=FilteredRelation(
        'mail_subscriptions', condition=Q(mail_subscriptions__mail_id=10)
    )
)
```

But FilteredRelation doesn’t support conditions that span relational fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need at all to do this with a `FilteredRelation`, you can write this like:

```
Subscription.objects.filter(
    email__id=mail_id
)
```

with *`mail_id`* the id of the `Email` object you wish to filter on.

Django will construct a query that looks like:

```
SELECT subscription.id, subscription.name
FROM subscription
INNER JOIN email_subscriptions
    ON subscription.id = email_subscriptions.subscription_id
WHERE email_subscriptions.email_id = email_id
```

There is no need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` anyway, since you check if the `mail_id` is a specific `id`, hence an `INNER JOIN` will result in the same set.

Note that you use a `ManyToManyField`, and that Django creates a table in between the two entities, but that you can not access that table, not unless you specify a model with a [**`through`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) parameter.

You can also annotate the `Subscription`s with an `is_subscribed`, like:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Subscription.objects.annotate(
    is_subscribed=Exists(
        Email.subscriptions.through.objects.filter(
            subscription_id=OuterRef('id'),
            mail_id=email_id
        )
    )
)
```

This then results in a query like:

```
SELECT subscription.*,
    EXISTS(
        SELECT U0.id, U0.email_id, U0.subscription_id
        FROM email_subscriptions U0
        WHERE U0.subscription_id = subscription.id AND U0.mail_id = email_id
    ) AS is_subscribed
FROM subscription
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, but I need to get the entire list of possible subscriptions so that I can specify the "is_subscribed" field, so I will use the left join. And I want to use nulls from "left join" for the "is_subscribed" field

Comment: Thanks, this works for me.
EXISTS in SELECT not too long?

Comment: @pylame22: normally if it a decent database system, it will "cut off" from the moment it has found a row.